# Does Calm Emotions still allow a saving throw?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, saving-throw

Old dragons can frighten you:

> **Frightful Presence.** Each creature of the dragon's choice that is within 120 feet of the dragon and aware of it must succeed on a DC 16 Wisdom saving throw or become frightened for 1 minute. A creature **can repeat the saving throw** at the end of each of its turns, ending the effect on itselfon a success.

Calm Emotion can suppress this:

> You can suppress any effect causing a target to be charmed or frightened. When this spell ends, any suppressed effeet resumes, provided that its duration
>   has not expired in the meantime.

Do you keep repeating the saving throw while the frightened condition is suppressed?

Comment: Related questions: "[While under a spell effect that's suspended, can you still make saving throws?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/117083)" and "[What happens if you become Immune to a condition, while suffering that condition?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96690)" and "[Does Antimagic Field suppress or prevent petrification from a creature ability?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/150188)"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Yes

The effect is suppressed, but it is not ended.  Frightful Presence specifically says that you can repeat the saving throw at the end of each of your turns.  Nothing in Calm Emotions changes that.  If the spell had another part, you wouldn't say that you don't get the saving throw.  I don't think it makes any sense to say that you don't get the saving throw since the only effect is suppressed.

---

Let's change the wording slightly:

> Cold: Each creature of the plaguebearer's choice that is within 120 feet of the plaguebearer must succeed on a DC 16 Constitution saving throw or become sickened for 1 minute. A creature can repeat the saving throw at the end of each of its turns, ending the effect on itself on a success.
>
> Cold Medicine: You can suppress any effect causing a target to be sickened. When this spell ends, any suppressed effect resumes, provided that its duration has not expired in the meantime.

Point being that your body is still working to fight off the infection, even if you don't see the symptom.

Comment: I'm torn between Dale M's interpretation and yours. The only thing that makes me (slightly) prefer his is that part of the spell's description : "_provided that its duration has not expired in the meantime_". If the wording had been "_provided the effect has not ended_", I'd have chosen your answer hands down. Still have to think this over.

Comment: @Meta4ic See my addendum.

Comment: I had this very example in mind when I wrote my comment (in fact, I was about to make a comment about causes and symptoms under Dale's answer), but then I thought about how, RAW, D&D isn't always about logic. As a DM, though, I would definitely allow that save, as it seems the most logical thing to do. But is it RAW? Anyway, you get my vote.

Comment: @Meta4ic I think given the ambiguities in the rulebook, both answers can be seen as possible interpretations of RAW.  I think mine is more RAW and correct, though. :)

Answer (score 8):

No, the key here is "suppress any effect"; while subject to the calm emotions you are **not** under the effect of the dragon's frightful presence. How can you save against something that is not affecting you?

Comment: How cold you _suppress_ something that is not affecting you? "Suppress" sounds like treating the symptoms, not the underlying condition.

Comment: @András you have the cart before the horse - it is not affecting you because it is suppressed, not the other way around.

Comment: Contrast: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/117086/9552